# ReactJS element doesn't reload after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

really quick problem on react state change.

I have a state `departments: []` that will receive value on componentDidMount.
And in `render()` I use `map function` to display all the items in that array.

The problem is when the first time the page is loaded, state `departments` isn't quite loaded yet but once it's loaded, the page doesnt render for that particular element.

Code:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    helpers.getAllDepartments().then(function(response){
        if (response !== this.state.departments) {
        this.setState({
            departments: response.data.department

        }, this.getOptions());
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
getOptions: function() {
    this.setState({
        isLoaded: true
    })
},
```

in render:

```
{
(this.state.isLoaded) ? this.state.departments.map((each, i) => {
return(
<option key={i} value={each}>{each}</option>
)
}) : <option>Nothing</option>
}
```

The result shows `Nothing`. When `console.log(this.state.departments)`. It shows 4 times.
The first one is blank, but from the second one it has values.

**UPDATE**
I tested with

```
 {(this.state.isLoaded)?<b>loaded</b>:<b>not loaded</b>}
```

The result is `loaded`. However the `array map function` doesn't update.

Comment: Did you check if your `isLoaded` value has updated or not?

Comment: I think doing `this.getOptions().bind(this)` might solve it.

Comment: @S.Patel yes it's updated. First, it's false and then turns into true.

Comment: Can you provide an example on CodeSandBox or anywhere else?

Comment: @S.Patel https://github.com/Mystr-Melbourne/Mystr/tree/Department-ListofDepartment. The code is in app->components->children->scheduleView.js

Comment: @S.Patel https://github.com/Mystr-Melbourne/Mystr/blob/Department-ListofDepartment/app/components/children/ScheduleView.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reasons, I added a className in the Selection DOM and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using callback `getOptions` to set half of the state outside? You could combine state changes in single setState call as follows:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    helpers.getAllDepartments().then(function(response){
        if (response !== this.state.departments) {
        this.setState({
            departments: response.data.department,
            isLoaded: true
        });
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```